# Grep Next Line Only If Two Lines Above Match String Consecutively

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm using the following command to match the following line in a file:

```
cat file.txt | grep -A 1 'match' > output.txt
```

This allows me to get the line after 'match' is found in the following file:

```
match
random text line 1
match
match
match
random text line 2
match
random text line 3
match
match
random text line 4
match
random text line 5
match
random text line 6
match
random text line 7
match
random text line 8
match
match
random text line 9
```

However, I need to return only the lines after 2 or more consecutive 'match' lines. In this case the output would be:

```
random text line 2
random text line 4
random text line 9
```

I have tried using a combination of `grep -A 2 'match' | grep -A 1 'match'` but it doesn't work as it's redundant. I'm stuck on how to match only if there are two consecutive lines. I'm open to using awk or sed for matching too if it's more efficient. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep stands for `g/re/p` i.e. it's for Globally finding a Regular Expression and Printing the result, **that is all**. That is not all that you are trying to do so therefore grep would be the wrong tool to try to use. For general purpose text manipulation the standard tool to use is awk:

```
$ awk '/match/{c++;next} c>1; {c=0}' file
random text line 2
random text line 4
random text line 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation too. This works well. I really need to use awk more. Seems like the cool (and accurate) thing to do :-)

Comment: Actually, it returns an incorrect 'random text line' when the order of lines goes `match, random text line 11, match, random text line 12, match, random text line 13`. In that case, line 13 would be outputted (even though it only has one 'match' above it not two). Can I edit your answer and provide the example where it fails?

Comment: That's one way of replicating it. But, I am getting lines that only have 1 'match' directly above it rather than 2 consecutive 'match' lines :-/

Comment: I get it. you need to ALWAYS clear `c`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thank you very very much Ed. I really appreciate your knowledge and skills.

Comment: You're welcome. I've already deleted my comments to tidy up the Q/A.